# Mixing valve lubrication

Tags: plumbing, lubrication

What can I use to clean and lubricate the moving parts (e.g. handle and its housing) of a shower mixing valve that doesn't move very smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this issue is caused by calcification in the valve caused by hard water. The best thing is to shut off the water and disassemble the valve as much as you can, cleaning the parts with vinegar or a commercial decalcifying agent. Get as much solvent as you can into the inner workings of the valve turning the mixing valve mechanism back and forth to loosen debris.
I usually try to prevent this problem by occasionally turning the control valve back and forth from limit to limit to free calcium before it builds up.

Answer (score 1):

**Plumber's Grease**, every decent plumber keeps a tub of it. I believe it is a special waterproof mixture of generally non-toxic silicones and petroleum base oils. Any good hardware store or plumbing shop will have it. I *never* reassemble a faucet without slathering the internal moving parts with it...